# set Allow GCM Registration Without APNS Token iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing this iOS application and this is not the first time where I deal with GCM but I am facing this `setAllowGCMRegistrationWithoutAPNSToken` bug and I am not able to find anything on internet !

This is ths bug message :

```
"[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GGLInstanceIDConfig defaultConfig]];"
```

This is ths code :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication )application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData )deviceToken {
// [END receive_apns_token]
// [START get_gcm_reg_token]
// Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with the default config and request a registration
// token to enable reception of notifications
[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GGLInstanceIDConfig defaultConfig]];
_registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                         kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES};
[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:_gcmSenderID
                                                    scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                  options:_registrationOptions
                                                  handler:_registrationHandler];
// [END get_gcm_reg_token]}
```

Comment: please add some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow this guide on [setting up a GCM App on IOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client).

Before you can receive messages, an iOS application needs to register with both Apple Push Notification service (APNs) and the GCM connection server. When a client app registers with GCM, it receives a registration token, which it must then send to the app server (the APNs device token is *not* sent to the server). The client app must store a boolean value indicating whether the registration token has been sent to the server.

To register with APNs and obtain a GCM registration token:

1. Include the GCM header: `#import <Google/CloudMessaging.h>`
2. Register for remote notifications and obtain an APNs token.
3. Configure and initialize [Instance ID](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/ios/api/interface_g_g_l_instance_i_d), and call `tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:options:handler:` with the following arguments:

   - The app server [sender ID](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#key)
   - The `kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM` scope, as defined in `GGLInstanceID.h`
   - The APNs token, set as part of the options dictionary, with the key `kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption` and the value set to the binary APNS token
   - `kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption` with a value of YES for sandbox or NO for production environment. This is part of the options dictionary.
4. Once you have retrieved the token, send it to your app server.

**For your bug message:**

```
[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GGLInstanceIDConfig defaultConfig]]
```

**try to replace it with**

```
[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:instanceIDConfig]
```

Check this [fix example of custom delegates](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/pull/40/files).